# Не работает type=module на локальном сервере python

Tags: javascript, python, html

```
<script src="/scripts/metamask.js" type="module"></script>
```

Не хочет работать скрипт к которому я указываю путь, в консоль выдает ошибку:

*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

В скрипте есть импорт поэтому модуль убрать не могу. Может ли быть проблема в сервере python и можно ли это как то решить или просто идти искать другой локальный сервер? Или ошибка где то у меня в тегах html?

Comment: У вас сервер однострочный то что: `python -m http.server`?

Comment: да, в нем нужно что то изменить?

Comment: Нет, я сам пользуюсь им и у меня всё работает) Думал если не этим пользуетесь то предложить. А путь точно правильный? Может надо с точки начать?

Comment: правильный) если я меняю тип на js/text и убираю импорт, то все работает

Comment: А можете показать весь код `html` и `js`? Но в максимально минимальном но воспроизводимом виде. Я бы скопипастил себе и попытался бы запустить

Comment: Я уверен что проблема не в самом коде. Проблема на таком уровне что у меня есть js файл(metamask) и он работает, там просто обычный js код без импортов, работает пока нет type="module", получается в таком виде <script src="/scripts/metamask.js""></script>, как только я дописываю модуль <script src="/scripts/metamask.js" type="module"></script>, то сразу появляется ошибка, и так с любым js файлом, независимо от кода в этом файле. то есть у меня даже не доходит до кода самого файла, жалуется просто на модуль в теге script

Comment: Спрошу просто на всякий случай)) Вы в браузере пишите `http://localhost:8000/index.html`?

Comment: да)) я говорю, сам джс файл у меня работает, я не могу использовать там импорты, мне нужно разбить его на части, для импорта нужен type="module". Я даже пустой файл джс оставлял и если есть модуль в теге, то будет и ошибка

Comment: я читал про ошибку, где то написали что ошибка со стороны сервера, но я просто не знаю настолько простых серверов как на питоне, слишком непонятные пока для меня, везде локалки идут для работы с php и весь материал идет вокруг этого, а мне для другого надо

Comment: Поробуйте запускать в других браузерах, у них бывают текст ошибки разный и это бывает полезно

Comment: дал другу протестить, у него всего работает)) буду надеяться что у меня на других браузерах все нормально будет